# brew unable to install jenkins-lts

Tags: jenkins, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to [install Jenkins-lts](http://jenkins.io/download/lts/macos/) on my macOS Monterey, but I keep getting this error:

[image]

This happens after running the first command on the download instruction page and im not sure why.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: can you run `brew doctor` and paste the results in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
~ echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/username/.zprofile
➜  ~ eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```